# Control Optimized Away

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have an asp.net class which inherits from Page.  I then have a checkboxlist and a button.  The checkbox list is populated manually using `Add` on the Load event handler.  The button then takes the checkbox list items and determines where to redirect.

```
class WebPage : Page
{
public Redirector Redirector {get; set;}

// Added on the .aspx Page
protected CheckBoxList CheckBoxList {get; set;}
protected Button ClickMe {get; set;}

void Page_Load(object s, EventArgs args)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    CheckBoxList.Add(new ListItem("a", 1));
    CheckBoxList.Add(new ListItem("b", 2));
  }
}

void handler(object s, args)
{
  Redirector.Items.Clear();
  foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected).ToList())
            {
                Redirector.Items.Add(item.Value);
            }
  Response.Redirect(Redirector.Url);
}

}
```

The problem I'm having is that the CheckBoxList is getting optimized away such that Redirector. Items is not updated which in turn doesn't update Redirector.Url (which uses Items). I'm pretty sure its getting optimzed away because if I set a breakpoint and expand the properties manually it works; or do a Debug.WriteLine. I'm guess this is because the values of the CheckBoxList are never used again on the new load.

There a clean way to fix this other than just doing a Console.WriteLine()?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an issue with how I implemented `.Items` and the interaction with `.Add` on the returned `List<T>`. The outside object `Ridirector` is not made aware of the change to its own list.

I should be using something like an `ObservableCollection`. My workaround was to do an assignment to `.Items` instead of using `.Add`.